# Browsing more applications (installed) in Unity

Tags: 11.04, unity

I just switched from Classic to Unity and found that I cant locate my other apps in the dashbord. I click "More Apps" and nothing happens ... I suspect I'm missing some packages as I actually installed a command line or bare system via the alternate CD (Command Line Install Option)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It worth checking that you have the following packages installed:

- unity-place-applications
- unity-place-files
- zeitgeist

Comment: I had the same problem and found the first two packages you listed were not installed.